# ListView with toolbar menu like function

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to ask a question regarding if it would be possible to make a toolbar like the droid tool bar's secondary items bar inside a listview? Picture shown below:

[image]

Comment: You can use Rg.plugins.popup and create custom popup, on click of icon inside listview

Comment: @MShah The problem is the position of the window.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do. You can put this panel with menu in the header of the listview if you dont mind it to scroll up with the data. Or you can create a grid with 2 rows, put menu panel in row 0, put listview in row 1.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out, gonna flag you up if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. If I understand it correctly, you would like to number the items of a list view.

This can be done by overriding the functionality of the getView() function.

Check for an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179876/how-to-number-items-in-a-list-view)

Comment: Sorry, but no, what I want to do is to create a list that has a 'secondary toolbar items' like in android if you have implemented the menu bar with secondary options

Comment: I think I now understand what you want. I have implemented a spinner before with dynamic elements. But seems you want to implement multiple spinners.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377361/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list) a link to implement a spinner. you might want to implement that more than once. You also have to give each spinner a different id and a different adapter.

Hope this helps.